# Como hacer para dejar seleccionado el ultimo "click" en un <option> que esta en un for()?

Tags: jquery, html5

La variable `${window.nombre}` es una variable global que contiene el id de una revista, pero no queda seleccionada cuando le doy click al botón de la revista, siempre me trae en último valor del `select`.

```
$.ajax({

        url:'MODEL/Menu_Model.php',
        success:function(data){
            $(".square_select_revistas").html("");
            var Data=JSON.parse(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
                var select = `
                    <option selected="${window.nombre}" value="${Data[i].id}" >
                        ${Data[i].nombre_revista}
                    </option>
                `
                $(".square_select_revistas").append(select);
            }
        }
    });

var modal = `

  <div class="square_modal col-sm-7">

      <label>Revista</label><br>

      <select id="revista" 

            class="square_select_revistas">

      </select>
  </div>
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

El atributo "selected" se puede usar de dos formas:

```
<option selected>Algún valor</option>
<option selected="selected">Algún valor</option>
```

Si quieres que el  de la revista cuyo id es el de la variable ${window.nombre} se seleccione debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({

    url:'MODEL/Menu_Model.php',
    success:function(data){
        $(".square_select_revistas").html("");
        var Data=JSON.parse(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
         if(Data[i].nombre_revista == ${window.nombre}){
            var select = `
                <option value="${Data[i].id}" selected>
                    ${Data[i].nombre_revista}
                </option>`;
         }else{
            var select = `
                <option value="${Data[i].id}" >
                    ${Data[i].nombre_revista}
                </option>`;
         }
            $(".square_select_revistas").append(select);
        }
    }
});
```

De esta forma estás comparando el nombre de la variable global con los nombres que te devuelve la petición AJAX y asignando el atributo "selected" solo al elemento que coincida.

Comment: Amigo he ahí el inconveniente, como esta en un for() entonces lo va a dejar seleccionado cada vez que de la vuelta hasta llegar al ultimo <option> que es donde quedaría seleccionado.